# webscraping the physiotherapie praxis list and expand all items list

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here i am trying to create a list of physiotherapist from German yellow pages. The actual number are 90+ and here i am getting 52, where 50 of them are the list and 2 of them are unwanted items. The yellow markings are the unwanted items. How can i remove those from the list and expand it all so that i get all the list from that page.

web_address ='https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Suche/Physiotherapie%20praxis/Rostock'

```
business_name = soup.find_all('articles', h2 ='data-wipe-name="Title"')
business_name = soup.find_all('h2')
for name in business_name:
   print(name.get_text())
print(business_name)
```

[image: Web-scraping List of Physiotherapist practitioner]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably it is getting from another h2 tag as your method is `find_all` on that tag you can specify `attrs` and remove that 2 unwanted items

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res=requests.get("https://www.gelbeseiten.de/Suche/Physiotherapie%20praxis/Rostock")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")

business_name = soup.find_all('h2',attrs={"data-wipe-name":"Titel"}) 
for name in business_name:
    print(name.get_text()) 


print(len(business_name))
```

Output:

```
Göllner Sabine Krankengymnastik & Physiotherapie
Friemel Physiotherapie Inh. B. Neumann Krankengymnastik & Physiotherapie
Nehrenberg Dorothee Physiotherapie
...
50
```